# Attending to each row of NSTableview to change image on Click-

Tags: macos, nsmutablearray, nstableview, nstableviewcell

I'm trying to add [this](http://juliuspaintings.co.uk/cgi-bin/paint_css/animatedPaint/070-NSTableView-ImageAndTextCell.pl) example's ImageAndTextCell.h class to my project. I have added it successfully. It looks something like below

[image: this]

On row click i get the selected index and on IBAction I need to change it to green color. Which works fine too. But when I click on another row, the previous rows green turns to red. Im sure the problem is with the logic of checking for the row. I have implemented the below code which failed

```
 - (NSCell *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tv dataCellForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {



NSTextFieldCell  *cell = [tableColumn dataCell];
if(tv== [self tableView]){
    if([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:COLUMN_TITLE]){
        if(![tickTracker count]){
            ImageAndTextCell *imageAndTextCell = (ImageAndTextCell *)cell;
            // Set the image here since the value returned from outlineView:objectValueForTableColumn:... didn't specify the image part...
            NSString *fileName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Cross" ofType:@"png"];
            NSImage *markerImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
            [imageAndTextCell setImage:markerImage];

        }else{
             for (int i= 0;i < [tickTracker count];i++){ 
              NSLog(@" 123 number %@",[tickTracker objectAtIndex:i]);
              NSInteger myInteger = [[tickTracker objectAtIndex:i] integerValue];
              [changedRows addObject:[tickTracker objectAtIndex:i]];


            if(row == myInteger){
                NSLog(@" %li value ",row);
                ImageAndTextCell *imageAndTextCell = (ImageAndTextCell *)cell;
                // Set the image here since the value returned from outlineView:objectValueForTableColumn:... didn't specify the image part...
                NSString *fileName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Tick" ofType:@"png"];
                NSImage *markerImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
                [imageAndTextCell setImage:markerImage];

            }else{
                 ImageAndTextCell *imageAndTextCell = (ImageAndTextCell *)cell;
                 // Set the image here since the value returned from outlineView:objectValueForTableColumn:... didn't specify the image part...
                NSString *fileName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Cross" ofType:@"png"];
                NSImage *markerImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
                [imageAndTextCell setImage:markerImage];
                }
            }
         }
   return cell;
  }
```

Can someone help me on this? The object at index 0 in tickTracker is not set to green when it checks for object at index 1.

**EDIT 1**. 
   Inside the ticktracker:

-(IBAction)method:(id)sender{

```
 NSUInteger idx = [[tableView selectedRowIndexes] firstIndex];

 while (idx != NSNotFound) {
    int rowKey = (int)idx;
    NSNumber* rowNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:rowKey];
    [tickTracker addObject:rowNumber];

    idx =[[tableView selectedRowIndexes] indexGreaterThanIndex:idx];



}
```

}

Ouput:

```
  NSLog(@" 123 number %@",[tickTracker objectAtIndex:i]);
  Output: 123 number 2
  NSLog(@" %li value ",row);
  2 value
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Declare a property `selectedCars` of type NSMutableDictionary. Init it. This replaces your "tickTracker".

2) You don't need an IBAction. Just override `tableViewSelectionDidChange`:

```
- (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [selectedCars addObject:@"yes" forKey:[[self tableView] selectedRow];
}
```

3) In `dataCellForTableColumn` replace

```
}else{
             for (int i= 0;i < [tickTracker count];i++){ 
              NSLog(@" 123 number %@",[tickTracker objectAtIndex:i]);
              NSInteger myInteger = [[tickTracker objectAtIndex:i] integerValue];
              [changedRows addObject:[tickTracker objectAtIndex:i]];


            if(row == myInteger){
```

with

```
}else{
   if ([self.selectedCars objectForKey:row]) {
      ... set the tick image ...
   } else {
      ... set the cross image ...
}
```

4) If you want to deselect rows, then check in the ...DidChange delegate method, if `selectedCars` is already set and delete the entry if true.

Comment: I don't get it - what is stored in tickTracker? Are you sure, you want to compare the value of tickTracker with the row of the tableView?

Comment: Please print also `row` in the first `NSLog` and show the output.

Comment: I don't understand, why you are using the `for`-loop. The whole method gets called for each cell individually and you can determine if the cell should be green by a check if `row` is found in tickTracker. IMO there's no need to iterate every time.

Comment: so how do i access every index of the tickTracker nsmutableArray?

Comment: and Yes I agree each cell is getting called for every iteration. Thats the issue. Is there a better alternative for this?

Comment: finally it works with: if([tickTracker containsObject:row]) { } Please do share yours. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   if([tickTracker containsObject:row]) { 


    }
```

This the settled issue. Aslong as the object row value is inside the tickTracker change the image.